# How to create product category column in woocommerce orders panel?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

How can I manage columns in wordpress for add new column getting product category in woocommerce orders panel. I already found a way to create new columns in entire panel but I don't know how to add.

```
//MANAGE COLUMNS
add_filter( 'manage_pagamento_posts_columns', 'green_filter_posts_columns' );
function green_filter_posts_columns( $columns ) {

  $columns = array(
     'cb' => $columns['cb'],
     'title' => __( 'Title' ),
     'pacote' => __( 'Pacote', 'green' ),
     'temporada' => __( 'Temporada', 'green' )
   );

 return $columns;
}
```

Comment: Product categories **are assigned to products, but NOT to orders** that can have many items from **different product categories**… A product can also have many categories and subcategories… Additionally`manage_pagamento_posts_columns` hook doesn't exist and your actual code doesn't work for that…

Comment: I found a way to solve this, you can see how in my answer.

Comment: **Nobody else than you can answer this question**. So this question / answer **is not really useful to the community,** as your question is not clear and detailed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to add columns in woocommerce orders panel. In this code I show how to add products categories in each order line filtering by product and removing repeated categories when it happen.

```
// ADDING A NEW COLUMN (keeping "Total" and "Actions" columns at the end)
    add_filter( 'manage_edit-shop_order_columns', 'custom_shop_order_column', 20 );
    function custom_shop_order_column($columns)
    {
       $reordered_columns = array();

       // Inserting columns to a specific location
       foreach( $columns as $key => $column){
           $reordered_columns[$key] = $column;
           if( $key ==  'order_status' ){
               // Inserting after "Status" column
               $reordered_columns['my-column1'] = __( 'Categorias','theme_domain');
           }
       }
       return $reordered_columns;
    }

    // Adding custom fields meta data for each new column (example)
    add_action( 'manage_shop_order_posts_custom_column' , 'custom_orders_list_column_content', 20, 2 );
    function custom_orders_list_column_content( $column, $post_id )
    {
       switch ( $column )
       {
           case 'my-column1' :

               $cats = '';
               $cats_final = '';
               $item_cats = array();

               $order = wc_get_order( $post_id );
               $order_data = $order->get_data();

               foreach ($order->get_items() as $item_key => $item_values):

                 ## Using WC_Order_Item methods ##

                 // Item ID is directly accessible from the $item_key in the foreach loop or
                 $item_id = $item_values->get_product_id();

                 $item_cat = get_the_terms($item_id, 'product_cat');
                 $item_cat = array_unique($item_cat);

                 foreach ( $item_cat as $term ) {
                     array_push($item_cats, $term->name);
                 }

               endforeach;

               $item_cats = array_unique($item_cats);

               foreach($item_cats as $item_final){
                 $cats_final .= $item_final.', ';
               }

               echo rtrim($cats_final,", ");

               break;
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't add comment to the answer above so I post a new one. The answer from doughfabris is almost working. I test on my dev-site and found **the code will work after remove** "`$item_cats = array_unique($item_cats);`" **below** "`$order_data = $order->get_data();`"

The code here tested and work fine for me. Thanks dougfabris!
BTW, how to make it only show the top level?

```
// ADDING A NEW COLUMN (keeping "Total" and "Actions" columns at the end)
add_filter( 'manage_edit-shop_order_columns', 'custom_shop_order_column', 20 );
function custom_shop_order_column($columns)
{
   $reordered_columns = array();

   // Inserting columns to a specific location
   foreach( $columns as $key => $column){
       $reordered_columns[$key] = $column;
       if( $key ==  'order_status' ){
           // Inserting after "Status" column
           $reordered_columns['my-column1'] = __( 'Categorias','theme_domain');
       }
   }
   return $reordered_columns;
}

// Adding custom fields meta data for each new column (example)
add_action( 'manage_shop_order_posts_custom_column' , 'custom_orders_list_column_content', 20, 2 );
function custom_orders_list_column_content( $column, $post_id )
{
   switch ( $column )
   {
       case 'my-column1' :

           $cats = '';
           $cats_final = '';
           $item_cats = array();

           $order = wc_get_order( $post_id );
           $order_data = $order->get_data();

           foreach ($order->get_items() as $item_key => $item_values):

             ## Using WC_Order_Item methods ##

             // Item ID is directly accessible from the $item_key in the foreach loop or
             $item_id = $item_values->get_product_id();

             $item_cat = get_the_terms($item_id, 'product_cat');


             foreach ( $item_cat as $term ) {
                 array_push($item_cats, $term->name);
             }

           endforeach;

           $item_cats = array_unique($item_cats);

           foreach($item_cats as $item_final){
             $cats_final .= $item_final.', ';
           }

           echo rtrim($cats_final,", ");

           break;
   }
}
```

Comment: Amazing to know that it worked for you. Feel free to vote in the question or in the answer, will help me with reputation!
The code **$item_cats = array_unique($item_cats)** is for remove repeated categories of a order, if the order has two products of two categories, for example. What you mean with "make it only show the top level"?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The top level I mean there are top categories and sub-categories. I only want to show the top category.

Comment: Oh ok! I'll work in this solutions and back here to show you!